# Google Script :: How to fix cannot read property "keyword" of undefined

Tags: google-apps-script

This is my first message here in the community, I hope you could help me because I'm newbie at coding. So far I've run this script to extract keywords related to my marketing campaigns and everything went OK, but I have a specific campaign that I've had to add not only google values, but also bing values, and now the script doesn't work, Anyone could help me?

I've tried to create variables like `bing_keyword`, and so on but so far nothing has worked. This script was already created by another colleague that is not in the company anymore and I don't know how to fix it.

I receive the error at line 34, when I run the script I have an error:

> TypeError: cannot read property "keyword" of undefined at line 34,

For variable `var keyword=dataSet2.data.data[fecha][keys].google.keyword;`

Here's my code:

```js
var url2 = "http://api.cognitiveseo.com/command.php?
apiKey="+apikey+"&command=getKeywordCampaign&campaignId="+cId+"&siteId="+siteId+"&dateFrom="+fDate+"&dateTo="+lDate+"&mobile=no";

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2, headers);

var dataSet2 = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

var fecha= first(dataSet2.data.data); 


  for (var keys in dataSet2.data.data[fecha]){
    var keyword=dataSet2.data.data[fecha][keys].google.keyword;            
    var locale=dataSet2.data.data[fecha][keys].google.locale;
    var position=dataSet2.data.data[fecha][keys].google.position;
    var kwUrl=dataSet2.data.data[fecha][keys].google.url;               


    var WORKINGSHEET_URL= searchDrive('Datos Cognitive '+cname);
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(WORKINGSHEET_URL);
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

    sheet.appendRow([fecha,keyword,locale,position,kwUrl,fecha]);
    //Logger.log(cname);
    //Logger.log(siteId);
    //Logger.log(keys);
  }
```

Comment: What does `Logger.log(fecha);` return?

Comment: Where do you retrieve `data` from? and what is `google` in `...data[fecha][keys].google.keyword;`

Comment: @AMolina I retrieve the data from the website cognitiveseo, which I have my marketing campaings, keywords, etc. If I run the code to depurate, in line 34 I obtain this info which is refering to the kewords I have in cognitive seo.

({google:{keyword:"spanischer schinken online kaufen", locale:"de-de", position:"24", url:"https://www.yourspanishshop.es/de/kaufen-spanischer-schinken/f-112", mobile:"no", location:""}})

where keyword, locale and so on belongs to one of these features.

Comment: ross @ross fecha should be return the info about these variables

var url2 = "http://api.cognitiveseo.com/command.php?
apiKey="+apikey+"&command=getKeywordCampaign&campaignId="+cId+"&siteId="+siteId+"&dateFrom="+fDate+"&dateTo="+lDate+"&mobile=no";
 
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2, headers); (where headers is  "contentType": "application/json")

 var dataSet2 = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

 var fecha= first(dataSet2.data.data);

Comment: I can tell what it *should* be doing, but is it actually returning the data you're expecting?

Comment: Can you add Logger.log(dataSet2) right after you define var dataSet2 ? Please cut and paste what you get. Also can you check if you really wanted to say var fecha= first(dataSet2.data.data); *and not* var fecha= first[dataSet2.data.data]?

Comment: @ross "fecha" is giving me the last date I've tried to extract data from the script, in this case 25-07-2019. So it seems that this variable runs ok.

Comment: @TanyaGupta after check the Logger.log info about dataset2 I have these info.

`[19-08-29 01:46:22:335 PDT] {data={data={2019-07-25={126|acheter sauce tomate solis={bing={mobile=no, location=, position=1, keyword=acheter sauce tomate solis, locale=fr-fr, url=https://www.yourspanishshop.es/fr/sauces-espagnoles/acheter-tomate-frites-solis/p-549}}, 18|buy pipas tijuana={google={mobile=no, location=, position=1, keyword=buy pipas tijuana, locale=en-uk, url=https://www.yourspanishshop.es/en/seeds-and-nuts/buy-pipas-tijuana-pipas-g-grefusa/p-228}}` and so on...

Comment: I'm thinking that could it be a problem when the loop for finds keywords related to bing. 

Could it be any way of obviate the results refering to **bing** inside the for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is happening because the code is expecting to find a variable where none exists. Your intuition that the code is failing when it only finds Bing results is correct.

For instance in the below, I have commented out the Google results for some of the items in the JSON

```
var sample = {
    "api": "cognitiveSEO API",
    "data": {
        "status": "success",
        "data": {
            "2015-01-10": {
                "google penguin": {
                    "locale": "en-us",
                    "google": {
                        "position": "26",
                        "url": "http:\/\/cognitiveseo.com\/blog\/6741\/google-penguin-3-0-recoveries-and-penalties-analysis\/"
                    },
                    "bing": {
                        "position": null,
                        "url": null
                    },
                    "yahoo": {
                        "position": null,
                        "url": null
                    }
                },
                "google penguin case study": {
                    "locale": "en-us",
//                    "google": {
//                        "position": "4",
//                        "url": "http:\/\/cognitiveseo.com\/blog\/803\/google-penguin-case-study\/"
//                    },
                    "bing": {
                        "position": "1",
                        "url": "http:\/\/cognitiveseo.com\/blog\/803\/google-penguin-case-study\/"
                    },
                    "yahoo": {
                        "position": "1",
                        "url": "http:\/\/cognitiveseo.com\/blog\/803\/google-penguin-case-study\/"
                    }
                },
                "penguin case study": {
//                    "locale": "en-us",
//                    "google": {
//                        "position": "8",
//                        "url": "http:\/\/cognitiveseo.com\/blog\/803\/google-penguin-case-study\/"
//                    },
                    "bing": {
                        "position": "5",
                        "url": "http:\/\/cognitiveseo.com\/blog\/803\/google-penguin-case-study\/"
                    },
                    "yahoo": {
                        "position": "5",
                        "url": "http:\/\/cognitiveseo.com\/blog\/803\/google-penguin-case-study\/"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "credits": 10
    },
    "time": 1.552
}
```

This should give an error with your current code, as Google results are commented out.

The code below should fix it. This roughly approximates your code. I am assuming fecha is a date string produced by a different function.

```
function extract_google () {

  //var fecha= first(dataSet2.data.data); 
  var fecha = "2015-01-10"
  var dataSet2 = sample

  for (var keys in dataSet2.data.data[fecha]){ 
    var una_fecha = dataSet2.data.data[fecha][keys];
    if (una_fecha && una_fecha.google) {
      var kwUrl=una_fecha.google.url        
      var keyword=una_fecha.google.keyword            
      var locale=una_fecha.google.locale 
      var position=una_fecha.google.position
      var kwUrl=una_fecha.google.url       
      Logger.log (kwUrl);
    }


  } 

}

}
```

JSON is a nested tree like structure, rather than a table structure. While the keys of a JSON object has to be a string or a number, the values can be objects. The values of the keys of these child objects can themselves again be objects. Many real world JSONs can be 8 or 9 level deep. All to say, another way to solve your problem is to use if-then-else to check each level of the JSON object. However in that case, you would have a 8 or 9 level nested if-then-else. You can use "short-circuiting" to avoid this. Not the most elegant code, but better than if-then-else for nested JSON but easy to understand once you get it. Basically the short-circuiting can convert a nested if else error checking for undefined fields to a simple single line of code. The depth of a field will not increase the complexity it will just add more clauses with &&s.

As logical expressions are evaluated left to right, they are tested for possible “short-circuit” opportunities using the following rules:

1. false && (anything) is short-circuit evaluated to false
2. true || (anything) is short-circuit evaluated to true

So the following line of code:

`if (una_fecha && una_fecha.google)`

is checking to see if there is a value in `una_fecha`. Then it checks to see if there is a value in `una_fecha.google`

More in this [Medium article I wrote on shortcircuiting](https://medium.com/the-n00b-code-chronicles/a-n00ber-pattern-for-taming-the-wild-data-web-da10e81a035c)

Comment: It worked!! Thank you so much for your help! Thanks to your code I've been able to extract not only google values, but also bing ones in other spreadsheet.

Mucha appreciated! :D